# Getting profiles list on a maven build

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, manifest.mf

On a maven build, i am adding a list of profiles.
I would like to write this list in the manifest.
Is there an attribute that I can use in order to put it in manifest entries?
Or may be there is a pluggin that I can use in order to have an attribute?

I've looked on internet, but didnt found answers.

Thanks,

J.Doe

Comment: Please look here
https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/examples/manifest-customization.html
Or
https://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/examples/manifestFile.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
In the links, i see : <manifestEntries>...</manifestEntries>. That's ok, I understand we can put new attributes thanks to this.
But i don't know what to put in order to add the Profiles chosen for the build.

Here is a picture : http://imgur.com/a/sMRTv.

I'm talking about the line Profiles : profile1 profile2 profile3.

I would want to have that in the manifest.mf in order to know quickly what are the profiles used for the application.

Comment: A am looking for an answer for this aswell. @suraj_fale 's answer is not helping for the core question: how to put profiles active on build to manifest file?